# Chance to Poison/Bleed works on Projectile/Traps?

Tags: path-of-exile

There are some skills that have "x% Chance to poison" like **Fatal Toxins** or **Toxic Strikes**.
[image]

And also, **Bleed chance** that can do "x% Chance to bleed".
[image]

My question is this:
 Do those skills work with traps and projectiles?

Comment: Yup! These passives work on anything that does Physical Damage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bleeds can only be applied by attacks dealing physical damage, this is why the passive node says "**Attacks** have 15% chance to cause bleeding". This does include projectile attacks like those from bows. You can also link bow skills like puncture to a trap support gem. So yes, depending on the set up you can cause bleeds with projectiles (from attacks) and traps.

Poison can be caused by any damaging hit (attack or spell, doesn't matter for poison) that deals physical and/or chaos damage, assuming you have some % chance to poison on hit affecting whatever skill you are trying to poison with.

Comment: "Poison can be caused by any (physical and/or chaos) damage source as long as it counts as a hit (meaning anything not a DoT effect)" was a bit confusing. But to clear that up: If I used elemental damage only (ex: lighting) will that also have chance to poison?

Comment: Poison damage is based off the physical and chaos damage of whatever skill is causing the poison. If the skill deals lightning then it won't poison. I will clear up that sentence.

Comment: There are exceptions, OFC. Volkuur's Guidance (unique gloves) can allow your cold damage to poison. And then there are uniques which convert other damage types to chaos damage, and that chaos damage can poison. Voltaxic Rift and the Consuming Dark are two I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are wrong.  the word "Attacks" reference the gem tag "Attack" so any skill gem or base action "attack" works with it.
Look at it this way for a more in depth analysis

1) If what it says is "Global" then everything concerning YOU is effected (no minions or auras)

2) Basic math is [Z has (+x% or +x) chance/to Y] as the Y is the effect and the Z is the type of action needed for the x to be adjusted.

- So if we need to do Z then we need to find things that can do Z (such as"Attack" in your example)